# iPhone: Creating Scrolling Image/Text Views within Modal View Tab Bars

Tags: iphone, xcode, view

I've just begun Objective-C and am looking to find a way to create an iPhone app that will launch with a Main Menu consisting of maybe around 8 or 9 buttons.

When the buttons are pressed it will link to a Scrolling Text view (containing a good few paragraphs of text) with an accompanying image at the top of the screen, which will act as a "Back" button to return to the Main Menu.  I was also looking it to animate/behave as a modalview (where the new view scrolls up from the bottom of the screen, and scrolls back down when dismissed/Back-button pressed).

I have got the Tab Views working within a modal view (which is brought up from pressing a button in the Main Menu) and have worked out how to assign a custom icon to each tab. I've also added a custom background for each Tab. Though I'm still having trouble adding scrolling views to each Tab, where I can insert pictures and text programmatically. I would really appreciate any help you could give me with this..

Thanks very much!!

.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MasseurViewController : UIViewController {
    UITabBarController *tbc;
}

-(IBAction)showHeadTabBar;
-(void)dismissTabBar;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITabBarController *tbc;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "MasseurViewController.h"

@implementation MasseurViewController

@synthesize tbc;

//---Implement all the possible Tab Bar views


-(IBAction)showHeadTabBar{

    //---Define Back button

    UIImage *backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"headBackButton.png"];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, backImage.size.width, backImage.size.height);
    [button setImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissTabBar) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, backImage.size.width, backImage.size.height);
    [button2 setImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissTabBar) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIButton *button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button3.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, backImage.size.width, backImage.size.height);
    [button3 setImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissTabBar) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //------------************TABS**************-------------------
    //-------------------------------------------------------------

    //---------------Declare View Controllers-----------
    //---------------------------TAB 1
    UIViewController *blueController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    blueController.title = @"Blue";
    blueController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBar1.png"];
    //---Add tabs & Tab names
    [blueController.view addSubview:button];
    blueController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    blueController.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mainMenuBKG.png"]];   


    //----TAB 2
    UIViewController *redController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    redController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    redController.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shouldersImage1.png"]];    



    //----TAB 3
    UIViewController *greenController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    greenController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    //--------------------------------------------------


    //---Instantiate tab bars

    tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    //---Create array of tabs
    tbc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:blueController, redController, greenController, nil];

    //---Select starting tab
    tbc.selectedViewController = blueController;

    //--------------------------------------------------


    //---Add tabs & Tab names

    [redController.view addSubview:button2];
    redController.title = @"Red";

    [greenController.view addSubview:button3];
    greenController.title = @"Green";


    //---Release Tab views
    [blueController release];
    [redController release];
    [greenController release];
    [self presentModalViewController:tbc animated:YES];


}

//---Code to dismiss Tab Bars
- (void)dismissTabBar {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [tbc release];
}


/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/


/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: in the future please give some time to format your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too general to illicit a good answer, but I'll try to point you in the right direction.

You do not have to create a separate .h/.m/.xib for each button - you probably want that main menu page with all the buttons to be controlled by a single view controller class (.h, .m) and it would probably be convenient to create all the buttons in a single .xib file.

The views you create for each button's action depends on what you want it to do.  If 3 of them just show an image, you could re-use a class called displayImageView, for example.

I suggest you get your app working with a single main view with a single button and action, and then figure out how to expand it to 8 or 9 actions.

And finally, I think you have a lot of reading to do.   [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Creating_an_iPhone_App/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007595) is a good place to start.  Good luck.

Comment: @Mike

Here's my workings so far.. I have got the Tab Views working within a modal view (which is brought up from pressing a button in the Main Menu) and have worked out how to assign a custom icon to each tab. I've also added a custom background for each Tab.
Though I'm still having trouble adding scrolling views to each Tab, where I can insert pictures and text programmatically.
I would really appreciate any help you could give me with this..

Comment: I must admit I'm confused what your interface looks like or is supposed to do.  If you want your user to push/pop 8 or 9 choices, @Irene is spot on: set up a UINavigationController with a UITableViewController as it's rootViewController.  Each row functions as a button to push a view onto the nav stack.  The view you push onto the stack would be a UIScrollView, and inside that, you can add your text and image views.

Comment: @Mike
Thanks for your quick response.  Basically on the first view the user sees there are multiple buttons. The code listed is for when one button from that view is pressed.
When pressed, it animates upwards with a Modal View, which has three Tab Bars (at the bottom of the view). At the top of the Modal View is an image, acting as a button to return to the Main Menu the user sees.

I'm looking to put a Scrolling View inside each of the tabs with different content in each, without using IB. So "blueController" has scrollable images, "redController" & "greenController" have text.
Thanks again!

Comment: FYI, BlueController has no tabBarItem property to set at the time you instantiate it, so that line won't do anything.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is UIScrollView *blueScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame <some frame>];  [blueController.view addSubview: blueScrollView];  UITextView *redScrollView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:<some frame>];  [redController.view addSubview:redScrollView];  Then add a UIImageView to redScrollView and set the text for blueScrollView and greenScrollView;

Comment: @Mike
Thank you so, so, so much!!  This is exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate all your help with this.  You're a star, mate!  Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome.  How about checking this as the selected answer and voting it up?  :-)

Comment: @Mike
One last question.. (sorry).. can you help with the code snippet to add the UIImageView to the blueScrollView -- then that's definitely ALL I will need.  I honestly appreciate your help; it's been great, since I'm still new to all this. PS: checked as selected answer -- I can't vote up until I have more reputation.

Comment: UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:<some frame>];   iv.image = <some UIImage>;  [blueScrollView addSubview:iv];  [iv release];

Answer (score 0):

What you describe seems to me a perfect fit for using a navigation controller.
Your "main" view should be a `UITableView`, and not 8 or 9 buttons. Then, every time that the user selects a row in this table, you push a detail view with the proper text. That means that you don't need an image to act as a "back" button, as this will be provided for you automatically by the navigation controller (it's this arrow-shaped back button on the top left corner).

Try to read more about basic application design patterns for the iPhone ([this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH1-SW1) is a good start) and if you want some sample code, try [CoreDataBooks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html) or something similar.

Good luck!